# Increase button width in theme

Tags: android, dialog, themes

> In my application i treat one activity as a dialog theme which have some buttons and text areas.
>       My problem is that buttons are in the theme as a smaller and also button text is not fully visible.Please anyone help me to increase theme size or some other answer to solve this problem thanks...`
>       Here i enclosed image and layout files.

[image]

> MyTheme is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#565656" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#ffff8080" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp" />

</shape>
```

> Layout File for Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw_taskid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewdis_listname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textviewdateid"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_date"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="@string/changedate" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_time"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_changetime"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="ChangeTime" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setalarm"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="Set-Alarm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_CancelAlarm"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="Cancel-Alarm" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that XML shape drawable is not a theme. Check out themes.xml

Comment: i am a new android please give me any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got a solution for this problem just i remove my layout weight and set the width as 150dp.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textviewdateid"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_date"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="@string/changedate" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

> Into

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textviewdateid"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnid_date"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
        android:text="@string/changedate"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```